# Does Microsoft Edge not support Bootstrap carousel transitions?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, microsoft-edge

I am using a bootstrap modal carousel with sliding transitions that work perfectly fine with Firefox, but I am unable to see them when using Microsoft Edge. Is the function simply not supported by Edge or can I add some code to make it work?

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" data-wrap="true">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="img/carouselImg1.jpg" alt="Logo">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3></h3>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/carouselImg2.jpg" alt="Image2993">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3></h3>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/carouselImg3.jpg" alt="Abc">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3></h3>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: We will need to see your code; transitions are supported in all major browsers.

Comment: The code above is missing a closing div tag, however if you add that back in it works just fine. Could you share the page that is failing. Perhaps it's another issue.

Comment: How does the page / output look like in MS Edge for you?

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome it starts auto, bu in Microsoft supports bootstrap carousel it doesn't start auto. When you click on the fist next item it wil be then activated. I can't figure out why. Maybe someone else knows a answer for this.